# Why does water stress lead to alkalinity of xylem sap in plants?

Tags: botany, physiology, ecology, plant-physiology

I was reading this book: **Plant Physiology and Development, Sixth Edition by Lincoln Taiz, Eduardo Zeiger, Ian M. Møller, and Angus Murphy** when this doubt came to my mind. Abscisic acid, the stress hormone, works to prevent water loss from a plant. Its mechanism of action requires the xylem sap of the plant to be alkaline. **I can't figure out how water stress in the plant body causes alkalinisation of the xylem sap.** The section in the book stated as follows:-

> During the early stages of water stress,however, the pH of the xylem sap becomes more alkaline,increasing from about pH 6.3 to about pH 7.2. 
>   Stress-induced alkalinization of the apoplast favors formation of the dissociated form of abscisic acid, ABA–, which does not readily cross membranes. Hence, less ABA enters the mesophyll cells, and more reaches the guard cells via the transpiration stream.

I'd be grateful if anyone out there can help.

Answer (score 1):

According to recent studies, drought stress does not consistently lead
to increases in the pH of xylem sap. One article which discusses
interspecies differences is [Vit Gloser, et al.](https://doi.org/10.1007/s11104-016-2962-6), "The dynamics of
xylem sap pH under drought: a universal response in herbs?," *Plant and
Soil* 409, nos. 1-2 (2016): 259-272.

As to what may have prompted the textbook authors to assert this, see an
earlier article by two of the coauthors of the Gloser essay: [Sally
Wilkinson and William J. Davies](https://doi.org/10.1104/pp.113.2.559), "Xylem sap pH increase: a drought
signal received at the apoplastic face of the guard cell that involves
the suppression of saturable abscisic acid uptake by the epidermal
symplast," *Plant Physiology* 113 (1997): 559-573. Wilkinson and Davies
summarize an earlier study: "Hartung and Radin (1989) found that the pH
of xylem sap from water-stressed *Phaseolus vulgaris* roots increased
from control levels of 6.3 to 7.2." (560)

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! It would be very helpful if you could elaborate on your answer.  For example: How do changes in the cation/anion ratio affect the pH?  Also did you mean to say that lower nitrate uptake causes the cation/anion ratio **to decrease**? ——— You may also wish to take the time to go through the [tour] and the help pages starting with [Answer] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: Pls elaborate. Don't just give references